# Change devexpress grid control column header caption

Tags: c#, header, devexpress, gridcontrol

Hai all,

How to change devexpress gridconrol `column header caption` using c#.
please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done using the following code in the Page_Load event:

```
ASPxGridView1.Columns[0].Caption = "Some Value";
```

Comment: sorry,am using win forms xtragrid control.For that this code enough...?

Comment: I wrote this code for the ASPxGridView, as ASP.NET grid control.  If you are using the XtraGrid, the code should be:

gridView1.Columns[0].Caption = "Some Caption";

Comment: While trying out this solution I noticed that it would work only if the Caption property on the column object was blank to begin with.